# PHP date function causes problems if input value is empty

Tags: php

I am using the following PHP code to get the upcoming date of a given day.
For example If the day given in "Tuesday" it will output 01-09-2020.
The function is to show upcoming sale dates of smartphones.

```
$saledate = "Tuesday"
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

function dayDate($day) {
    return new DateTime('next ' . $day);
}
$nextsale = dayDate($saledate);

if(!empty($saledate)) {
    echo "Next Flash Sale on $saledate "; 
    echo $nextsale->format('d-m-Y'); // 01-09-2020
}
```

The problem is if the `$saledate` is empty, it causes the entire web page to not load. What could be the issue ?

This is what the errorlog says

> [25-Aug-2020 18:47:15 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dayDate() in /home/customer/www/sitename.com/public_html/index.php:1114
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/customer/www/sitename.com/public_html/index.php on line 1114

Update: Fixed by adding the `$nextsale = dayDate($saledate);` inside the if block.

Comment: Which line in this code is line 1114? `$nextsale = dayDate($saledate);`? Is this inside a class?

Comment: Put `$nextsale = dayDate($saledate);` inside the guarded block (`if`).

Comment: That error doesn't match the issue you mention, unless you only define `dayDate()` if `$salesdate` isn't empty but try to call it regardless. I can see how `new DateTime('next ' . $day)` fails and throws a fatal if `$day` is empty though since only having `next ` isn't a valid format.

Comment: You might want to use an IDE/Editor with syntax highlighting and error checking, which might help pinpoint the issue. You're missing a semi-colon on the first line, but considering the line number in your error message, I have a feeling that there's more to the code than is here that might be causing the issue.

Comment: @kerbh0lz  line 1114 is the `return new DateTime('next ' . $day);`, yes it is inside a class. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Yoshi, adding the $nextsale = dayDate($saledate); inside the guarded block (if) fixed the issue. Thank You